# (How) Can I find questions/answers from users who have removed their accounts?

Tags: feature-request, search, deleted-users

When a user deletes her/his account the questions and answers they posted remain but the username is removed and replaced with user#XYZ. When I put a one of those user 'names' in the site search I get random hits. For example user2110 posted an answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27659/7034) but when searching for this user name I get 1 result, a [question that user posted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27751/how-can-i-make-the-experience-of-eating-more-holy). Why does the site not show all results, I think being able to do so would be beneficial.

Comment: "removed and replaced with user#XYZ" That's not always true. It could be replaced with any text, such as "anonymous".

Comment: @DoubleAA that's for either 1.0 users who never transitioned to 2.0 (1.0 name shows w/no link), migrations where the person doesn't have an account here (uses the name from the other site), or disassociated posts (uses anon).  I think deleted non-ancient accounts are always user####.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think a) there is no official guarantee of such consistency, at least for non-automated actions, and b) you can request other text based on circumstances. Are these strings available in the DE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The on-site search doesn't support searching for posts from deleted users, but you can use [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/738230/get-all-posts-by-user) to find all posts from any user name.  Note that that query uses *name*, not *user number*, so you have to formulate the parameter as "user####" rather than "####" and (I assume; didn't test) if you search for a name used by more than one user, you'd get all their results.  Both of these limitations could be fixed with some edits to that query (but I don't have time to do it right now so I'm just giving a the starting point instead).

SEDE data is updated weekly, on Sunday mornings.